# How to fix Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

At 'currentTarget', i get an error when i run my code.

I have tried researching the problem but i cant find anything that works

```
// London is active by defult
document.getElementById("London").style.display = "block";
event.currentTarget.className += " active";

function openCity(cityName) {

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  let tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  let tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  event.currentTarget.className += "active";
}
```

index.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of 
undefined  at index.js:12

Comment: `event` is the argument to an event listener. None of this code is in an event listener function, so what do you expect `event` to be?

Answer (score 0):

None of this code is in an event listener, so there's no `event` variable. I'm guessing you want to add the class to the same element you just set the style of.

Instead of operating on the `className` string, it's better to use functions on the `classList`.

```
// London is active by defult
var defaultElement = document.getElementById("London");
defaultElement.style.display = "block";
defaultElement.classList.add("active");

function openCity(cityName) {

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  let tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (let i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  let tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (let i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  var newElement = document.getElementById(cityName);
  newElement.style.display = "block";
  newElement.classList.add("active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your function parameter event which you defining in html code
For example: `onclick="openCity(event)"`